# A Neverending cforest

Tags: r, random-forest

how can I decouple the time cforest/ctree takes to construct a tree from the number of columns in the data?

I thought the option `mtry` could be used to do just that, i.e. the help says

> number of input variables randomly sampled as candidates at each node for random forest like algorithms.

But while that does randomize the output trees it doesn't decouple the CPU time from the number of columns, e.g.

```
p<-proc.time()

ctree(gs.Fit~.,
      data=Aspekte.Fit[,1:60],
      controls=ctree_control(mincriterion=0,
                             maxdepth=2,
                             mtry=1))

proc.time()-p
```

takes twice as long as the same with `Aspekte.Fit[,1:30]` (btw. all variables are boolean). Why? Where does it scale with the number of columns?

As I see it the algorithm should:

1. At each node randomly select two columns.
2. Use them to split the response. (no scaling because of `mincriterion=0`)
3. Proceed to the next node (for a total of 3 due to `maxdepth=2`)

without being influenced by the column total.

Thx for pointing out the error of my ways

Comment: In other circumstances, R authors warn against using formula like `response~.` in the case of many covariates, as depending on how the formula is parsed, this can incur a large amount of overhead. I know this is the case for `randomForest`, which is why they explicitly provide a non-formula interface. I do not know if this is also a problem with `ctree`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the input, and that is an interesting idea. Unfortunately ctree doesn't seem to support a different input schema and randomForest is worse, a lot worse. There the computing time grows **exponentially** with the number of covariates despite fixed mtry and maxnodes.